# I want to be able to select multiple check-boxes simultaneously? Java SWT

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I have created several radio buttons but for some reason I can only select one and if I select another the previously selected radio button will suddenly become unchecked.

code:

```
package demo;

import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;

public class example {

    protected Shell shell;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            example window = new example();
            window.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Open the window.
     */
    public void open() {
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        createContents();
        shell.open();
        shell.layout();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create contents of the window.
     */
    protected void createContents() {
        shell = new Shell();
        shell.setSize(450, 300);
        shell.setText("SWT Application");

        Button btnRadioButton = new Button(shell, SWT.RADIO);
        btnRadioButton.setBounds(83, 10, 90, 16);
        btnRadioButton.setText("Radio Button");

        Button btnRadioButton_1 = new Button(shell, SWT.RADIO);
        btnRadioButton_1.setBounds(55, 86, 90, 16);
        btnRadioButton_1.setText("Radio Button");

        Button btnRadioButton_2 = new Button(shell, SWT.RADIO);
        btnRadioButton_2.setBounds(179, 158, 90, 16);
        btnRadioButton_2.setText("Radio Button");

        Button btnRadioButton_3 = new Button(shell, SWT.RADIO);
        btnRadioButton_3.setBounds(293, 65, 90, 16);
        btnRadioButton_3.setText("Radio Button");

        Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.RADIO);
        button.setText("Radio Button");
        button.setBounds(303, 103, 90, 16);

        Button button_1 = new Button(shell, SWT.RADIO);
        button_1.setText("Radio Button");
        button_1.setBounds(189, 196, 90, 16);

    }
}
```

I want radio buttons 1,2 and 3 to be linked so only one of these can be selected simultaneously. But I'd like 4,5 and 6 to be in a separate group etc.

How can I fix this, thanks?

Example of use:

*Answer Question one using radio buttons 1, 2 and 3*

*Answer Question two using radio buttons 4, 5 and 6*

*etc.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SWT, you should create the buttons in a Composite to form a group. All 6 buttons are being created in the same composite (shell), so they all are in the same group.

```
    shell = new Shell();
    shell.setSize(450, 300);
    shell.setText("SWT Application");

    Button btnRadioButton = new Button(shell, SWT.RADIO);
    btnRadioButton.setBounds(0, 10, 90, 16);
    btnRadioButton.setText("Radio Button");

    Button btnRadioButton_1 = new Button(shell, SWT.RADIO);
    btnRadioButton_1.setBounds(0, 30, 90, 16);
    btnRadioButton_1.setText("Radio Button");

    Button btnRadioButton_2 = new Button(shell, SWT.RADIO);
    btnRadioButton_2.setBounds(0, 50, 90, 16);
    btnRadioButton_2.setText("Radio Button");

    Composite composite = new Composite(shell, SWT.NULL);
    composite.setBounds(0, 70, 300, 200);
    composite.setLayout(new RowLayout());

    Button btnRadioButton_3 = new Button(composite, SWT.RADIO);
    btnRadioButton_3.setBounds(0, 0, 90, 16);
    btnRadioButton_3.setText("Radio Button");

    Button button = new Button(composite, SWT.RADIO);
    button.setText("Radio Button");
    button.setBounds(0, 20, 90, 16);

    Button button_1 = new Button(composite, SWT.RADIO);
    button_1.setText("Radio Button");
    button_1.setBounds(0, 40, 90, 16);
```

Comment: how can I follow this example to group radio buttons described above e.g. btnRadioButton, btnRadioButton_1 and btnRadioButton_2

Comment: When I attempt the above, the last three radio buttons become invisible

Comment: That's because when you change buttons parent, you need to adjust x and y bounds.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a [CheckBoxGroup](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CheckboxGroup.html).

> The CheckboxGroup class is used to group together a set of Checkbox
>   buttons. Exactly one check box button in a CheckboxGroup can be in the
>   "on" state at any given time. Pushing any button sets its state to
>   "on" and forces any other button that is in the "on" state into the
>   "off" state.
>
> The following code example produces a new check box group, with three
>   check boxes:

Example for awt:

```
CheckboxGroup cbg = new CheckboxGroup();
add(new Checkbox("one", cbg, true));
add(new Checkbox("two", cbg, false));
add(new Checkbox("three", cbg, false));
```

---

For Swing you have to use [ButtonGroup](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)

```
//In initialization code:
//Create the radio buttons.
JRadioButton birdButton = new JRadioButton(birdString);
birdButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_B);
birdButton.setActionCommand(birdString);
birdButton.setSelected(true);

JRadioButton catButton = new JRadioButton(catString);
catButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);
catButton.setActionCommand(catString);

JRadioButton dogButton = new JRadioButton(dogString);
dogButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_D);
dogButton.setActionCommand(dogString);

JRadioButton rabbitButton = new JRadioButton(rabbitString);
rabbitButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_R);
rabbitButton.setActionCommand(rabbitString);

JRadioButton pigButton = new JRadioButton(pigString);
pigButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_P);
pigButton.setActionCommand(pigString);

//Group the radio buttons.
ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
group.add(birdButton);
group.add(catButton);
group.add(dogButton);
group.add(rabbitButton);
group.add(pigButton);
```

---

And finally for SWT you can use the [Composite](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/AddRadioButtonstoaCompositetoformagroup.htm)

```
public class RadioButtonComposite {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    Composite composite = new Composite(shell, SWT.NULL);
    composite.setLayout(new RowLayout());

    Button mrButton = new Button(composite, SWT.RADIO);
    mrButton.setText("Mr.");
    Button mrsButton = new Button(composite, SWT.RADIO);
    mrsButton.setText("Mrs.");
    Button msButton = new Button(composite, SWT.RADIO);
    msButton.setText("Ms.");
    Button drButton = new Button(composite, SWT.RADIO);
    drButton.setText("Dr.");

    shell.open();
    // Set up the event loop.
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
      if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
        // If no more entries in event queue
        display.sleep();
      }
    }
    display.dispose();
  }

}
```

Comment: how can I follow this example to group radio buttons described above e.g. btnRadioButton, btnRadioButton_1 and btnRadioButton_2

Comment: Above you have used different types of buttons. I want to use SWT radio buttons, do you know how to accomplish this?

Comment: @MuratK. Based on the fact that this question is tagged with `swt` you can probably remove the sections of your answer about AWT/Swing.